# Indeterminate limit algebraic method

Tags: limits

Friends, I am stuck with this problem: what is the limit of

$$\lim_{x\to-2}\frac{x^2-2}{x^3+8}$$

Comment: As it stands the limit does not exist, If the numerator were either $x-2$ or $x^2 -4$ then we could do something with it

Comment: I suspect a typo has crept into the problem formulation.  You might want to double-check.

Answer (score 2):

The proposed limit does not exist. Indeed, on one hand we have

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to-2^{+}}\frac{x^{2} - 2}{x^{3} + 8} = +\infty
\end{align*}

On the other hand, we have

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to-2^{-}}\frac{x^{2} - 2}{x^{3} + 8} = -\infty
\end{align*}